# Extract data in between parentheses and append at the end of the line

Tags: python, python-3.x

File.txt:

```
first_name NVARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
middle_name NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
last_name NVARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,

output i need:->output.txt
first_name NVARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,15
middle_name NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,20
last_name NVARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,11
```

How can I extract data in `File.txt` between parentheses and append at the end of the line?

Comment: What have you tried? Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: import re
hand = open('newfile.csv')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall(r"\(([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\)", line)
    if len(x) > 0 :
        print (x)                                             its printing only the length

Answer (score -1):

Use regex - something like:

```
import re
for line in input:
    m=re.search('\((\d+)\)',line)
    output.write(line.rstrip('\n')+m.group(1)+'\n')
```

The search content should match what you are looking for (`\d+` in my example - matches any number). If you expect more then one parentheses in a sentence then you should give some more info. But in general, to extract a part of a match to your regex, use parentheses around what you wish to extract, and use `group(index)` on the retrieved "match item" (`m` in the example) - where `index` is the index of the parentheses you put in your regex that their content you wish to retrieve (and 0 means the entire match).

For example:

```
m=re.search('a(.)c(.)e','abcde')
m.group(0)
'abcde'
m.group(1)
'b'
m.group(2)
'd'
```

Comment: I guess it's because you're providing an answer to a poor question.